# Implicit casting obscures overloaded operator. How to resolve?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, operator-overloading

I have a fairly complicated construct. I'm also fairly certain I've been staring at it for way too long, and all those trees now obscure my view of the forest. So I'll give you the full complication of my construct, even though I suspect only a small portion of it is actually relevant.

Now, my construct in words:

- A templated baseclass, derived from its own baseclass, implements several operator overloads.
- Classes subclassed from the templated baseclass (using their own name as template parameter) will have access to all the operators. This construct ensures that operators can only operate on equal types, as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742728/derive-overloaded-operator-but-operate-on-same-types-only).
- A single specific subclass implements a few specialized versions of the operators. Call this class `Derived`. This subclass also uses named constructors, so its main constructor is `private`.
- Another baseclass implements cast operators to `double` and to `Derived`, to enable its subclasses to be (implicitly) cast to `Derived` type. Call one of these base classes `OtherDerived`.
- Instances of `Derived` can then be constructed either by a call to one of the the named constructors in `Derived`, or by a pass through `OtherDerived` as in `Derived D = OtherDerived(5.0);`

My problems:

1. Defining `Derived D = OtherDerived(5.0) * 2.0;` seems to cast `OtherDerived(5.0)` to *double* instead of `Derived`, so that the multiplication by `2.0` is simply a product of doubles, and NOT the output of `operator*` in `Derived`'s base class.
2. The definition of `operator*=` in the templated base class cannot return a reference to `*this`, since the type of `*this` is `BaseClass<T>` while the desired type of the reference is just `T&`.

How to resolve these issues elegantly?

I consider the second problem minor, since I can easily work around it by not returning a reference at all. Still, it would be nice to have one. Most important to me though is: how do I enable people to write `Derived D = OtherDerived(...) * 2.0` or some similar, simple form?

Demanding people to write

- `Derived D = (Derived)OtherDerived(...) * 2.0;`, or
- `Derived D = OtherDerived(...) * Derived::someName(2.0);`, or
- `Derived D = OtherDerived(...).operator*(2.0);`

etc. seems rather strange and unnecessary...

NB: preferably, the `operator double()` remains available :)

Here is an MWE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

class SuperBase
{
public:
    virtual ~SuperBase(){}
    SuperBase() : value(0.0) {}

protected:
    double value;
    SuperBase(double value) : value(value) {}
};

template <class T>
class Base : public SuperBase
{
public:
    virtual ~Base(){}
    Base() : SuperBase() {}

    T& operator*=(double F)       { value *= F; return *this; }
    T  operator* (double F) const { return T(value*F); }

    double operator*(const T& U) const {
        return value*U.value;
    }

protected:
    double value;
    Base(double value) : SuperBase(value) {}
};

class Derived final : public Base<Derived>
{
public:

    ~Derived(){}
    Derived() : Base<Derived>(){}

    static Derived someName(double value) {
        return Derived(value);
    }

    Derived operator*(const Derived& D) const {
        return Derived(value/D.value);
    }

private:
    Derived(double value) : Base<Derived>(value) {}
};




class OtherBase
{
public:
    virtual ~OtherBase(){}

    operator double () { return value; }
    operator Derived() { return Derived::someName(value); }

protected:
    double value;
};

class OtherDerived final : public OtherBase
{
public:
    ~OtherDerived(){}

    OtherDerived(double value){
        this->value = std::sqrt(value);
    }
};



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Derived a = OtherDerived(1.05);     // Compiles fine

    Derived b = OtherDerived(1.05);     // Compiles fine
    b *= 2.0;                           // Error: cannot cast Base<Derived>
                                        // to Derived

    Derived c = OtherDerived(1.05)*2.0; // Error: casts the
                                        // OtherDerived to double,
                                        // so Derived(double) gets
                                        // called, which is private

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case #2 of your `main` code, your problem seems to stem from the fact you would like your `Base<Derived>` class to create a `Derived` object inside of `Base<Derived>::operator*=` when the constructor for `Derived` is private ... you'll have to make the `Base<Derived>` class a friend of `Derived` in order for the constructor to be called.

For case #3 of your `main` code, I would define a `operator*` for your `OtherBase` or `OtherDerived` class to prevent the implicit casting to `double`.

Comment: As for case #2 that was my first guess too, so I added `friend class Base<Derived>;` to `Derived`. I then get `error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘Derived&’ from expression of type ‘Base<Derived>’`. I then started implementing a cast operator in `Base<T>` from `*this` to `T`, but then realized the operator would return a reference to a temporary. So...still stuck.

Comment: As for case #3, see @Andrey's answer. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Once you define the overloaded `operator*` for double on your `OtherDerived` class, you really don't need the conversion to `double` unless there is some other reason beyond working with standard math operators ... so if we comment that out, then your code works fine.  Here is an example: http://ideone.com/BIx4i

Comment: Hey, perhaps I see a light: how about deriving `OtherBase` from `Base<Derived>`? Can I get away with that?

Comment: Well, really in the end you need to find a way to avoid the implicit casts that are ambiguous, and can't be made explicit because you've declared the appropriate constructors private.  In the case I mentioned above, and that means getting rid of the `operator double()`, and replacing those use cases with the appropriate operator that takes a `double` as an argument.  What you mentioned at face-value seems like it could work as well, and you could remove the `operator Derived()`.

Answer (score 1):

`Derived::operator*` hides `Base::operator*`. Try inserting `using Base::operator*` in class `Derived` to make `operator*(double)` available in `Derived`.

Comment: In `Base<T>`, the operator is defined for  both `const T&` and `double` as input. `Derived::operator*(const &Derived)` then simply specializes the Base definition, so hiding `Base<Derived>::operator*` is exactly the intention...can you elaborate a bit more what you mean?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis - it also hides `operator*(double)`, not sure whether this is really intended. But I see now that this is not the cause of the problems.

Comment: Hey, perhaps I see a light: how about deriving `OtherBase` from `Base<Derived>`? Can I get away with that?

Answer (score 1):

For problem #1, you can implement a standalone multiplication operator:

```
Derived operator*(const OtherDerived& op1, double op2)
  {
  return (Derived)val1*Derived::someName(val2);
  }
```

In addition, both conversion operators in `OtherBase` should be `const`.

Comment: Except that this does not work as-is -- I get `error: call of overloaded ‘Derived(const OtherDerived&)’ is ambiguous`. For the life of me, I can't see why that would be happening...

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis: that's because `OtherBase::operator Derived` is non-const.

Comment: Well, using a combination of @Henrik's addition and this one gets me nearly there. Now the only thing it's nagging about is the `b*=2.0;` statement.

Comment: Still, it seems kind of fugly to have to define separate operators for all `OtherDerived`-type classes, since I have perfectly well-defined operators defined all the way in `Base`...But oh well, such is life.

Comment: Hey, perhaps I see a light: how about deriving `OtherBase` from `Base<Derived>`? Can I get away with that?